# How to format code in html / css / js/ php

Tags: html, pretty-print

I'm looking for a way to automatically format and color code I write in an HTML document. I know wikipedia does it, for example on the page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_function

I'm sure there are libraries out there to do this, but I can't for the life of me, find one. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Have a look at the [Prettify JavaScript](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) library. It's the one generally used by people (it's the one being used here on SO, for example.)

You would use it like this:

**In your `<head>` element:**

```
<link href="prettify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="prettify.js"></script>
```

**In your `<body>` element:**

```
<body onload="prettyPrint()">
  <!-- any HTML you like here... -->
  <pre class="prettyprint">
def say_hi():
    print("Hello World!")
  </pre>
  <!-- any HTML you like here... -->
</body>
```

That's for simple use of the library. If you're using other JavaScript on your page I would recommend other methods for enabling the Prettify library (i.e., don't use the `onload` attribute of the `<body>` element.) For example, if you're using jQuery, I wrote this jQuery plugin that I usually use to syntax highlight certain elements:

```
// Extend jQuery functionality to support prettify as a prettify() method.
jQuery.fn.prettify = function () { this.html(prettyPrintOne(this.html())); };
```

Used like this:

```
$('#my-code-element').prettify();
```

Answer (score 11):

This is an old question, but as it came up first in Google for me, I thought I'd add another option. While Prettify is still a serviceable option, it's showing its age a bit. A newer library I ran across is [Prism](http://prismjs.com/), and it seems to work rather well. It's more semantic and gives finer-grained control over how to format your code. It also supports plugins and its themes look nicer out of the box than Prettify's.

Comment: I'd be really unsettled by adding anything called prism to my code... : p

Answer (score 6):

I think a simpler and powerful solution are [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/). It support 169 languages at this time and 77 code styles (like Solarized dark and light). Some more:

- automatic language detection
- multi-language code highlighting
- available for node.js
- works with any markup
- compatible with any js framework

Quick setup:

**1 - In HTML head:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.9.0/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.9.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

**2 - In your HTML content**

```
<pre>
   <code class="html">
      <p>This is your HMTL sample</p>
      <p>You can use classes like "html", "php", "css", "javascript" too..</p>
   </code>
</pre>
```

You can check the languages and styles [here](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/).