# how to deal with the innerHTML of pre in IE678,where is the indentation?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

who can tell me how to deal with the innerHTML of pre in **IE678**  ?
I know to use br, but how to do with the indentation?

My **HTML**:

```
<div id="box">
    <pre id="code">

       var a = "before";
       function b(){
           alert(a);
       }

    </pre>
</div>
```

My **JS**:

```
<script>
    var pre = document.getElementById("code");
    var str = pre.innerHTML;
    var newstr = str.replace("before", "after").replace(/\n/ig, "<br />");
    pre.innerHTML = newstr;
</script>
```

Right **result** in page:

```
var a = "after";
function b(){
    alert(a);    //note the indentation before alert 
}
```

Error **result** in page of **IE678**:

```
var a = "after"; 
function b(){ 
alert(a);        //indentation is disappeared......
}
```

Comment: formatting code in html pages is not that easy. Maybe have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270221/how-to-format-code-in-html-css-js-php they mention prettyprit javascript library for this. Note that I've opened the pre tag in IE8 and ident works without having to add br.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, didn't see you changing the text of the pre with JavaScript that messes it up. Here is what you can do:

```
    var pre = document.getElementById("code");
    var str = (pre.innerText) ? pre.innerText : pre.textContent;
    var newstr = str.replace("before", "after");//.replace(/\n/ig, "<br />");
    if(pre.textContent){pre.textContent = newstr};
    if(pre.innerText){pre.innerText = newstr};
```

Comment: var newstr = str.replace("before", "<a style='color:red'>before</a>"); Do like that,your code is out of work

Comment: Like I said in my first reply; if you want to make it complicated use a javascript library. Who is the say the html markup inside the string should be rendered as html or text? When is it text and when is it html?

Comment: Now what I should do? If I want to show right format which contain html tags in IE678?

Comment: Not sure if this will help: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/ How will you know that markup needs to be rendered or not? For example would you like to render <a> or display it as text in the following example: var a="<a>{%1}</a>";