# angular.js binding expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a pastebin-like app. I want to be able to paste in code, and output the code to a user, with some highlightings and other fanciness. The code can be of ANY language. I use google's prettify.js for this.

The code is saved in a db as a string. Heres how i get the data:

```
$http.get('/paste/' + $scope.paste).success(getCallback);

var getCallback = function(data) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.paste = data[0].code;
        $scope.$apply();
    }, 0);
};
```

So far so good. When i want to apply some highlighting to the pasted code i have done this.

```
app.filter('pretty', function() {
    return function(text) {
        // a method in the prettify.js
        return prettyPrintOne(text, '', true);
    };
});
```

And i apply it like this:

```
<pre ng-bind-html="paste|pretty"></pre>
```

The result is a nice-looking paste. However the angular sanitizer fails when theres tags like `<?php` of similar that it does not understand, or tags that are pure html elements `<div>` So how could i bind the expression with the html formatting to the paste.

If i only do `ng-bind`i actually get the correct data showing, including tags like `<?php` (in html comments?) but the formatting goes out of the window.

Comment: to see if I understand it: you want to keep displaying code (using bind-html), and at the same time apply html style formatting to that code?

Comment: have you taken a look at this?    http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Comment: @Jorg Yeah, the code needs to be styled, not just "plain" there has to be code highlighting. The prettify gives me generated html, and that can be bound to ng-bind-html, but the parser dont dig html/php (possibly other language) elements.

Comment: @Mark-Sullivan Yeah, just had a look at that. Will have to investigate  on how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like prettify.js does not understand PHP correctly. When you enter some PHP code, it just creates a line which is not commented. This works using $sce with JavaScript and other languages supported by "prettify.js" though:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ajQrnmBB83SLmFvzfiBr?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your Plunker. However, i'm absolutely sure that this is not a prettify.js thing. If you try your plunker with a html element it will also fail. In fact anything with starting with "<"  will fail. (<div>, <?php etc..) This is def a problem with the sanitizer/ng-bind.

Comment: I have updated the Plunkr with a small PHP snippet and console.log(text). At least the "prettyPrintOne" function gives me that:`"<ol class="linenums"><li class="L0"><!--?php 
  echo phpinfo() 
?--></li></ol>"`. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270221/how-to-format-code-in-html-css-js-php, PRISM is a better alternative to prettify.js - it is even used on Brendan Eich's personal blog. https://soundcloud.com/istdochmiregal/neo-magazin-prism-is-a-dancer

Comment: Ok, thanks, ill investigate further. I have already implemented prettyprint, but maybe ill try with the nsa.js instead and open a backdoor.