# How to format JavaScript code snippet to display on Web Page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to format JavaScript code snippet to display on a web page as follow:-

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
     <code class="javascript"><script> $(document).ready(function(){ setTimeout(function(){ console.log('deleting cookie'); $.cookie('cookie',null,{domain: document.domain}); },1000); }); </script></code>
  </pre>
```

I got the clue from this SO [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270221/how-to-format-code-in-html-css-js-php).

I have included all the files and followed the instrucntion but its not formatting it rather showing the snippet as combined.

Here is a screen shot [image]

I am getting the code from json file that is why it is in a single line.

I have removed the `<script>` and the result is same.

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
         <code class="javascript">$(document).ready(function(){ setTimeout(function(){ console.log('deleting cookie'); $.cookie('cookie',null,{domain: document.domain}); },1000); });</code>
      </pre>
```

Any clue how may I intend it properly ?

Comment: 1: this is real script, so it _will run_, it is not inert text. 2: did you remember to set the CSS for `script { display: block; }` or something? Because script elements are not shown by default, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @ MikePomax I have removed the script tag still its the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to show the indents, you need to format the content in a multi-line string.

```js
document.getElementById('src').textContent = 
`
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   setTimeout(function(){ 
      console.log('deleting cookie'); 
      $.cookie('cookie',null,{domain: document.domain}); 
   },1000); });
`;
```

```html
<pre class="prettyprint">
     <code class="javascript" id="src"></code>
</pre>
```

BTW, please do not use `document.getElementById('src').innerHTML = xxx`, since `<script>` inside the string would be valid javascript code and would be executed

Comment: I am reading it from json file and cannot do it in a multi line.

Comment: I don't think the google's code prettify supports auto-indent or auto-format the code, which is going to be too heavy, since there are too many programming languages to cover...